# Functional programming pattern for performing a function once after fold/reduce?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming and was wondering if there is any kind of formal pattern/data type where 1) we fold/reduce with a monoid, 2) run a function once to get some summary out of the reduced value. For example, to get the mean of an array, we could reduce into a `[count, sum]` tuple and then finally divide the sum by the count once the reduce is done. Here's my implementation in TypeScript (will blow up for empty array):

```
const reduceSummarize = <T, U, V>(
  array: T[],
  reducefn: (result: U, nextValue: T) => U,
  initialValue: U,
  afterfn: (result: U) => V
) => {
  return afterfn(array.reduce(reducefn, initialValue));
};

const incrementCountSum = (
  countSumTuple: [number, number],
  nextValue: number
): [number, number] => [countSumTuple[0] + 1, countSumTuple[1] + nextValue];

const tupleRatio = (tuple: [number, number]) => tuple[1] / tuple[0];

reduceSummarize([1, 2, 3, 4], incrementCountSum, [0, 0], tupleRatio) // 2.5
```

Does a pattern like this have a name?

Comment: you already wrote the answer: `afterfn(array.reduce(reducefn, initialValue))` that's functional programming.

Comment: yes, reminds me of one project whose developer would write something along the lines of `fn.Curry(fn.Const, 42)` instead of `function() {return 42;}` . Losing touch with the ground!

Comment: "*will blow up for empty array*" - will it? You seem to be passing an `initialValue` just fine. (Sure, it returns `NaN`, but not throw an exception)

Answer (score 22):

*TL;DR: function composition.*

I'm getting the impression that, while this question is tagged *typescript*, solutions in other languages may be acceptable. I may be wrong, in which case I apologise and you can simply ignore the answer, but I'll answer with Haskell but link to various articles I've written which has code examples in C#, F#, and Haskell (with an emphasis on C#).

Haskell is often considered the gold standard for functional programming, for various reasons that I'm not going to cover here...

Generally, functions that fold or reduce are named *fold*, *reduce*, or something along those lines. The odd man out is, as usual, C# where it's called [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate). For a list/array/finite sequence you can typically fold from the left *or* the right, so some languages will provide functions called *foldLeft*, *foldRight*, or something to that effect.

Haskell calls these [foldl](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) and [foldr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr). So far, I haven't answered any of the explicit questions, but we're getting there.

Let's forget *right fold* for now and instead concentrate on the *left fold*. The actual Haskell type of `foldl` is more general than the following, but simplified, the type is something like this:

```
(b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Here, `a` and `b` are generic types (in TypeScript typically denoted `T`, `U`, `V`, or similar). The first part `(b -> a -> b)` is a function which is used with every `a` value in the list. The `b` value is an initial value to get started.

As an example, say that you want to reduce a list of numbers to the sum of those numbers. While this function tends to be built into most languages (including Haskell), we can implement it from `foldl` for didactic purposes:

```
ghci> foldl (+) 0 [3,7,2]
12
```

In Haskell it's possible to pass operators around as functions, so `(+)` is just the normal addition operator. You initialise the reduction with `0` and then add each `x` in the list `[3,7,2]` to the accumulated value, finally arriving at the result `12`.

While the general type of `foldl` involves *two* generic types `a` and `b`, nothing prevents them from being the same, in which case you have a function of a type like this:

```
(a -> a -> a) -> a -> [a] -> a
```

This looks promising.

## Monoid

What if we knew something more about the values in the list? What if we knew that the values are members of a set that gives rise to a monoid?

In that case, we'd use monoidal identity to kick things off. That's the role of the `0` in the above expression. Furthermore, we'd use monoidal 'append' in order to accumulate a running sum, adding each of the values to it.

How you'd model that depends on the language. Some languages might use interfaces to model monoids, while Haskell uses type classes. Basing behaviour on the type system often works well, but with monoids we're faced with the problem that for some types there are infinitely many possible monoids. For example, for numbers, you can't just talk about 'the number monoid', because even here, there are infinitely many - addition and multiplication being just two of them.

In Haskell, we wrap values in new types to disambiguate. Thus, a 'naked' `Integer` has no inherent monoidal nature, because the language doesn't know which one the programmer wants to use. If we want the addition monoid, we wrap numbers in a type called `Sum`, and we can now add them together using the monoidal `<>` (*append*) operator:

```
ghci> Sum 1 <> Sum 2
Sum {getSum = 3}
```

As you can see, the result is another `Sum` value with the number `3` inside. You can easily extract the value with the `getSum` function:

```
ghci> getSum (Sum 1 <> Sum 2)
3
```

I'm not, however, going to consistently do that here. Just know that it's possible.

If you have a list of 'naked' numbers, you can map them to a list of `Sum` values:

```
ghci> fmap Sum [3,7,2]
[Sum {getSum = 3},Sum {getSum = 7},Sum {getSum = 2}]
```

I apologise for approaching the question in such a roundabout manner, but now we're ready to move on. As the next step, we can rewrite our addition expression using Haskell's `Monoid` type class and the `Sum` instance:

```
ghci> foldl (<>) mempty (fmap Sum [3,7,2])
Sum {getSum = 12}
```

where `mempty` is the monoidal identity, here `Sum {getSum = 0}`.

Taking a list of monoids and reducing it to a single value is [common enough](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/11/20/monoids-accumulate) that it's a reusable function. In Haskell it's called [mconcat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mconcat). You can generalise it further and define it over every data structure that supports iteration, in which case you arrive at a function simply called [fold](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).

Here's the sum of numbers 'implemented' with `fold`:

```
ghci> fold (fmap Sum [3,7,2])
Sum {getSum = 12}
```

So far, this covers how to sum a list of numbers, but there are more challenges before we're done.

## Counting

How do we count the number of elements in a list? Use the built-in function for that?

Sure, we could do that, but what if we only had monoids to work with? And no built-in [length](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) function?

It's possible to count values using another monoid. Essentially, counting just means adding *1* for every value you see. This suggests a specialisation of addition...

Essentially, we want to take an arbitrary list like

```
[3,7,2]
```

and replace each value with `1`:

```
[1,1,1]
```

If we did that, we could then add all the ones together.

That's easy to do by defining a little helper function called `count` (surprisingly enough not a name that's already taken):

```
count _ = Sum 1
```

This is a function that ignores (`_`) the input and always returns `Sum 1`. This means that we can use it to count single values:

```
ghci> count 42
Sum {getSum = 1}
ghci> count "foo"
Sum {getSum = 1}
```

How many `42` values are there? `1`. How many `"foo"` strings are there? `1`.

Trivial, perhaps, but this means that we have a way to replace each value in a list with a special 'counting monoid':

```
ghci> fmap count [3,7,2]
[Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 1}]
```

Since `Sum` is a `Monoid` instance, it follows that we can `fold` it:

```
ghci> fold (fmap count [3,7,2])
Sum {getSum = 3}
```

What if we have an empty list? That works, too:

```
ghci> fold (fmap count [])
Sum {getSum = 0}
```

This works because the monoidal identity of `Sum` is `Sum 0`.

## Tuples

How do we fold to a tuple of values, like the OPs count and sum?

Fortunately, [tuples of monoids are also monoids](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/30/tuple-monoids), and we now have a monoid that can count, and one that can add. The next step, then, is to turn each value in a list into a tuple.

Fortunately, Haskell defines a [&&&](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) fanout operator that can do this:

```
ghci> (count &&& Sum) 3
(Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 3})
```

The result is a tuple where the first element is our 'counting monoid', and the second one is the standard addition monoid.

This means that we have a way to elevate each 'naked' number to such a tuple:

```
ghci> fmap (count &&& Sum) [3,7,2]
[(Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 3}),
 (Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 7}),
 (Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 2})]
```

Since tuples of monoids are monoids, we can `fold` this list as well:

```
ghci> fold (fmap (count &&& Sum) [3,7,2])
(Sum {getSum = 3},Sum {getSum = 12})
```

If you're worried about all the wrappers, we can easily unwrap the numbers. You could use standard pattern matching, or use the [Bifunctor](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/12/24/bifunctors) nature of tuples:

```
ghci> bimap getSum getSum (fold (fmap (count &&& Sum) [3,7,2]))
(3,12)
```

The result, mind, is a *tuple* of numbers, *not* a list of numbers.

## Division

Given a tuple of numbers, how do we divide them? This is fairly trivial, but let's still go over it.

The OP wanted the intermediary result `[count, sum]`, and while JavaScript/TypeScript doesn't (I think) distinguish between lists and tuples, Haskell does. A tuple's size is fixed at compile time, whereas a list can have any size (length).

So far we have a tuple `(count, sum)` and we want to divide `sum` by `count`; i.e. `sum / count`. We can use the normal division operator for this, but we have to swap the values around.

No worries, Haskell has a [swap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v:swap) function too:

```
ghci> swap (3,12)
(12,3)
```

Great, but can we apply `(12,3)` to the division operator `/`? Not quite, because Haskell functions and operators are [curried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), so we need to [uncurry](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:uncurry) it:

```
ghci> uncurry (/) (swap (3,12))
4.0
```

As is always the case with division, this is not going to work if the divisor is `0`, but I'll leave that detail for another time.

## Composition

Let's summarise:

- We have a way to `fold` any `Foldable` data structure that contains monoidal values.
- We have a way to further produce a value from the result of the first step.

How do we compose them?

Specifically, let's make a function out of each of these:

```
countSum xs = bimap getSum getSum (fold (fmap (count &&& Sum) xs))
avg tpl = uncurry (/) (swap tpl)
```

How do you compose them so that first you execute `countSum` and then you pass the output from that to `avg`. That's standard [function composition](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2021/11/22/functions-as-pipes): `avg . countSum`. Haskell composes functions from right to left, so this syntax means: first run `countSum` and then `avg`:

```
ghci> (avg . countSum) [3,7,2]
4.0
```

To conclude, if I understand the OP right, the answer is: *standard function composition*.

Comment: If you change `count &&& Sum` to `Sum &&& count`, then you don't need to use `swap` later, right?

Comment: Excellent tutorial!  I hope the title of the question is sufficient to get lots of people to see this.  (Or ... maybe ... you could put some kind of overall heading in your answer to entice search engines?)

Comment: @TysonWilliams Yes, you are right. I chose to compose things the other way around in order to match the OP's order of `count` before `sum`. Oddly, I distinctly recall writing a comment to that effect, but it looks like it was lost in an edit along the way...

Comment: I say in my answer that the question contains what is probably unnecessarily complicated Typescript, and I think that this answer arrives at unnecessarily complicated Haskell -- the best number-averaging function is I think just `fromIntegral (sum list) / fromIntegral (length list)`, unless you really want to avoid traversing the list twice. (Of course, you're trying to introduce general concepts, and this isn't a very important point in this context -- but, if you agree, it might be worth noting.)

Comment: "*TypeScript doesn't distinguish between lists and tuples*" - it does, actually, in the type system (`[number, number]` vs `number[])`); it's JavaScript that has only arrays.

Comment: I think `avg` should be defined as simply `avg (count, sum) = sum / count`, not using any fancy higher-order functions. But if you want to go for it, I'm surprised you didn't define it as `avg = uncurry (/) . swap` or `avg = uncurry $ flip (/)`

Comment: I understand a little bit, but I still can't fully understand it, but I think this answer should be very professional, and I hope to have more and more detailed explanations.

Answer (score 5):

The other answer has a correct TL;DR ("function composition.", in case it gets edited away), but the rest of it doesn't really look like a good answer to *this* question, to me.

It may be better for the asker to explain why function composition suffices by using Typescript, so that's what I'll do. We can define function composition as a higher-order function (same as in Haskell):

```js
function compose<A,B,C>(f1: (val: B) => C, f2: (val: A) => B): (val: A) => C {
    return val => f1(f2(val));
}
```

Then we can build an averaging function by only using `compose`:

```js
const specificFold = (arr: number[]) => arr.reduce(([sum, count], elt) => [sum + elt, ++count] as [number, number], [0, 0] as [number, number]);
const divideTuple = ([a, b]: [number, number]) => a / b;

console.log(compose(divideTuple, specificFold)([1, 2, 3, 4])) // 2.5
```

(The type assertions are necessary for the thing to type check with the most restrictive types I could think of; you can inline `specificFold` and `divideTuple`, but then the code starts looking deliberately obfuscated.)

What this teaches us is that function composition is a general concept which subsumes what we're trying to do. Learning functional programming is often about learning how a very surprising amount of things fall under the same general concept; if function composition suffices to express your problem, you're supposed to just notice that that's nifty and leave it at that. It *is* nifty! and I suppose it may be called deep. But there's no reason to think about it much further.

By the way, I don't think anyone should define `compose` above in a production TS codebase. Typescript isn't Haskell. The syntax for generic higher-order functions is painful, so you should just express composition by repeated function calls, the way you originally did. There's nothing that lets you express the concept of a monoid as well as Haskell does it, so I wouldn't even try -- in fact, I don't think I'd write your very generic function at all; I'd just do things with the concrete types I had before me, and then go on with my day. Compare your original code (or the mess in my code blocks above) with

```js
function average(array: number[]): number {
   let total = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
   return total / array.length;
}
```

and consider readability.

Comment: " I don't think anyone should define compose above in a production TS codebase." agree in this *specific* case, but not in general there are still good uses for compose, this just isn't one of them.

Comment: What does the code in this answer return when the array is empty?

Comment: Nothing good -- just like the code in the question. Since the asker is aware of the issue and is asking about something different, I left it in.